# Filtering SQL query by row and by date range

Tags: sql, oracle, date, reduce

I have a time indexed Oracle DB which I'm trying to query by date range. I also want to do data reduction in the query so I don't get overwhelmed with too much data.

The stand alone date query (2352 rows in 0.203s):

```
select oracle_time from t_ssv_soh_packets0
where oracle_time >= TIMESTAMP '2009-01-01 00:00:00' 
AND oracle_time <= TIMESTAMP '2009-01-31 00:00:00'
```

The stand along reduction query (1017 in 0.89s):

```
select oracle_time from t_ssv_soh_packets0
where (rowid,0) in (select rowid, mod(rownum,50) from t_ssv_soh_packets0)
```

When I try to combine them it takes forever (48 rows in 32.547s):

```
select oracle_time from t_ssv_soh_packets0
where oracle_time >= TIMESTAMP '2009-01-01 00:00:00' 
AND oracle_time <= TIMESTAMP '2009-01-31 00:00:00' 
AND (rowid,0) in (select rowid, mod(rownum,50) from t_ssv_soh_packets0)
```

Obviously I'm doing something fundamentally wrong here but I don't know how else to both query by date and reduce the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to both 'Narveson' and 'nate c' for the pointers I finally figured it out. Here is the (probably Oracle specific) query that I came up with:

`select oracle_time from t_ssv_soh_packets0 where oracle_time >= TIMESTAMP '2009-01-01 00:00:00' AND oracle_time <= TIMESTAMP '2009-01-31 00:00:00' group by oracle_time, rownum having mod(rownum, 50)=0`

This query returns 47 rows in 0.031s. The original time query had 2352 rows so that makes sense.

The [ORAFAQ](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/SQL_FAQ) helped me get to the final solution.

Answer (score 2):

You are evaluating your reduction logic against rows that are not in your chosen date range.

Apply the reduction logic to a subquery containing your date range.

LATER:
Here's what I meant.

```
select oracle_time from (
  select oracle_time, rownum as limited_row_num
  from t_ssv_soh_packets0 
  where oracle_time >= TIMESTAMP '2009-01-01 00:00:00'  
  AND oracle_time <= TIMESTAMP '2009-01-31 00:00:00'  
) as time_range
where mod(limited_row_num,50) =  0
```

Comment: Your query does not work in Oracle which is the DB I'm stuck using. I'm not sure how to translate it into a subquery Oracle likes. I think the 'group by' clause is the most cross DB compatible.

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of the `in`

Why use this?:

```
select oracle_time from t_ssv_soh_packets0
where (rowid,0) in (select rowid, mod(rownum,50) from t_ssv_soh_packets0)
```

Your only condition is mod(rownum, 50)

```
select * from t where mod(rownum, 50)=0
```

last line should be `AND mod(rownnum,50)=0` not a self join with an `in`.

Comment: Looks like I mistakenly changed my table name 't_ssv_soh_packets0' to 'table' in my example. I'm trying to get this data which is all stored in 't_ssv_soh_packets0'. Your query doesn't work and Oracle seems to think the problem is with the join line, specifically with the 'as packets'. I'm getting 'missing keyword' error.

Comment: Oracle does not always support 'as' as its not ANSI-complaint. Its good to say if your using Oracle in the post.

Comment: This query: `select oracle_time from t_ssv_soh_packets0 where mod(rownum, 50)=0` selects 0 rows.

Comment: I thought something like this `select t1.oracle_time from t_ssv_soh_packets0 t1 left join t_ssv_soh_packets0 t2 on mod(rownum, 100)=0` would work but it acted like the mod wasn't even there.

Answer (score 1):

You can also let Oracle choose a random sample from the result by applying the [SAMPLE()](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_10002.htm#i2065953) clause:

```
SELECT oracle_time 
FROM t_ssv_soh_packets0
WHERE ...
SAMPLE(50)
```

Will return randomly 50% percent of the rows

Comment: Your comment was truncated. I got the following to work: `SELECT oracle_time FROM t_ssv_soh_packets0 SAMPLE(50) WHERE oracle_time >= TIMESTAMP '2009-01-01 00:00:00' AND oracle_time <= TIMESTAMP '2009-01-31 00:00:00'` This returned 1182 rows in 0.1s.

Comment: Strange, I edited my code sample. For some reason SO doesn't like WHERE and SAMPLE()